# Character converting funtion std::isupper() & std::islower() C++17

Tags: c++, c++17

I created a simple program to check whether the letter that a user has inputed is either uppercase or lowercase and then convert the lowercase to uppercase and the uppercase to lowercase using the `std::isupper()` and `std::islower()` funtion. upon running the code I get the character converion in number form instead of the expected uppercase/lowercase equivalent. Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char letter {};

    std::cout << "Enter a letter:";

    std::cin >> letter;

    if (std::isupper(letter))
    {
        std::cout << "You entered an uppercase letter"
                     "\n"
                     "the lowercase equivalent is:"
                  << std::tolower(letter);
    }

    if (std::islower(letter))    
    {
        std::cout << "You entered a lowercase letter"
                     "\n"
                     "the uppercase equivalent is:"
                  << std::toupper(letter);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example of an output below:

```
Enter a letter:F
You entered an uppercase letter.
The lowercase equivalent is:102

Enter a letter:f
You entered a lowercase letter.
The uppercase equivalent is:70
```

Comment: Where is a question?

Comment: I created a simple program to check whether the letter that
a user has inputed is either uppercase or lowercase and then
convert the lowercase to uppercase and the uppercase to lowercase
using the std::isupper() and std::islower() funtion.

upon running the code I get the character converion in number
form instead of the expected uppercase/lowercase equivalent.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting that area

Comment: @Code_Infinity please don't write comments for clarification but [edit] your question and put all clarifications _there_.

Comment: @Code_Infinity should cast the `std::tolower(letter)` or `std::toupper(letter)` output to `char`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(std::isupper(letter))
{

  std::cout<<"You entered an uppercase letter"<<"\n"

  "the lowercase equivalent is:" << (char)std::tolower(letter);
}

if (std::islower(letter))

{

  std::cout<<"You entered a lowercase letter"<<"\n"

  "the uppercase equivalent is:" << (char)std::toupper(letter);

}

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: @Code_Infinity Note: the C style cast used in this answer is often considered bad style in C++. Better not get into the habit of using it.

Comment: @hyde what is the difference between c style cast and c++ style cast. Actually they are doing same thing an output manner.It is a coding issue which is "just dont use C in C++ vice versa". Could you clarify it a little bit, thanks.

Comment: @Nazim C-style casts are dangerous. You are basically telling compiler "I don't care about type safety, do *everything* to make this type another type". C++ style casts have greater degree of control, e.g. `static_cast` wouldn't cast away constness by accident. This is well explained in [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50442/c-style-casts-or-c-style-casts) on [softwareengineering.se]

Comment: Even better explanation when to use which cast: [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast, reinterpret_cast, "C-style and Function-style" be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332030/when-should-static-cast-dynamic-cast-const-cast-and-reinterpret-cast-be-used/332086#332086)

Answer (score 9):

`std::tolower` and `std::toupper` return `int`, not `char` (<s>due to it's legacy origin from C</s>there are certain requirements due to which `int` was chosen, see footnote).

You can cast it back to char to get expected results:

```
static_cast<char>(std::tolower(letter));
```

Or you could save the result in a `char` variable before (if you need that converted latter elsewhere):

```
letter = std::tolower(letter);
std::cout << letter;
```

---

Note: As noticed by [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4706785/peter) in comment, there are requirements for `std::tolower` and `std::toupper` that mandate use of type bigger than type actually needed. Quoting it below:

> They are also specified as being able to accept and return `EOF` - a value that cannot be represented as a char but can be represented as an int. C++ iostreams (certainly no legacy from C, being specializations of the templated `std::basic_istream`) have a `get()` function with no arguments that reads a character from the stream, and returns an integral type larger than the character type being read. It is part of the machinery of being able to read a single character from a file and deal with error conditions.

Comment: `toupper()` and `tolower()` returning `int` is not just a "legacy from C". They are also specified as being able to accept and return `EOF` - a value that cannot be represented as a `char` but can be represented as an `int`. C++ iostreams (certainly no legacy from C, being specialisations of the templated `std::basic_istream`) have a `get()` function with no arguments that reads a character from the stream, and returns an integral type larger than the character type being read. It is part of the machinery of being able to read a single character from a file and deal with error conditions.

Answer (score 2):

### 1. option

You can use [`std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower) and [`std::toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/toupper) from **`<locale>`** header that return the type you would expect them to return.

Take a look at the examples:

```cpp
char c {'T'};
std::cout << std::tolower(c, std::locale()) << std::endl; // output: t
```

and

```cpp
char c {'t'};
std::cout << std::toupper(c, std::locale()) << std::endl; // output: T
```

Check [live example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:12,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:12,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:12,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:12),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Clocale%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++char+c1+%7B!'t!'%7D%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+std::toupper(c1,+std::locale())+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%0A++++char+c2+%7B!'T!'%7D%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+std::tolower(c2,+std::locale())+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.85494633014216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

### 2. option

You can use [`std::tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) and [`std::toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) from **`<cctype>`** header that return `int` that you need to cast to `char`.

Here are the examples:

```cpp
char c {'T'};
std::cout << static_cast<char>(std::tolower(c)) << std::endl; // output: t
```

and

```cpp
char c {'t'};
std::cout << static_cast<char>(std::toupper(c)) << std::endl; // output: T
```

Check [live example](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:67,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:67,selectionStartLineNumber:6,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:5),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccctype%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++char+c1+%7B!'t!'%7D%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+static_cast%3Cchar%3E(std::toupper(c1))+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%0A++++char+c2+%7B!'T!'%7D%3B%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+static_cast%3Cchar%3E(std::tolower(c2))+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:49.85494633014216,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50.145053669857845,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

You can also create your own handy helper functions:

```cpp
char toupper(char c) {
    return static_cast<char>(std::toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)));
}

char tolower(char c) {
    return static_cast<char>(std::tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)));
}
```

which you can use like this:

```cpp
char c1 {'T'};
char c2 {'t'};
std::cout << tolower(c1) << std::endl; // output: t
std::cout << toupper(c2) << std::endl; // output: T
```